# How to calculate means and std at once in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

For example, we have data like :

```
>>> df
   name  score  times
0   tom    100      1
1   tom     99      2
2   tom    100      3
3  jack     99      1
4  jack     99      2
5  tony    100      1
6  tony    100      2
7  tony    100      3
```

I want to get a result like

```
   name       score std
0  jack   99.000000  0
1   tom   99.666667  0.57
2  tony  100.000000  0
```

Is it possible to get the result at once?
Now I have to calculate them seperately and combine the result

Answer (score 8):

you can apply `agg` functon for calculate `mean`

```
df = df.groupby('name').agg({'score': ['mean', 'std']})
```

then you will get multiindex dataFrame, to extract level do following.

```
df = df.xs('score', axis=1, drop_level=True)
    # 'score' : key on which to get cross section
    # axis=1 : get cross section of column
    # drop_level=True : returns cross section without the multilevel index
```

As you given output do following:

```
df = df.reset_index('name')
```

Then rename

```
df.rename(columns={"mean":"score"}, inplace=True)
```

output:

```
   name       score      std
0  jack   99.000000  0.00000
1   tom   99.666667  0.57735
2  tony  100.000000  0.00000
```

Comment: Glad can help! If my answer was helpful, don't forget accept it. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

using `agg`

```
In [274]: df.groupby('name').agg({'score': ['mean', 'std']})
Out[274]:
           score
            mean      std
name
jack   99.000000  0.00000
tom    99.666667  0.57735
tony  100.000000  0.00000
```

Answer (score 0):

To get exactly what you need, you can group by name first, calculate mean and std on score and then rename and reindex.

```
(
     df.groupby('name').score.agg(['mean','std'])
       .rename(columns={'mean':'score'}).reset_index()
)
Out[204]: 
   name       score      std
0  jack   99.000000  0.00000
1   tom   99.666667  0.57735
2  tony  100.000000  0.00000
```